# Divide a network into two subnets of equal size

Tags: networking

I have been given the following IP 192.168.14.137/25 and asked to divide the network into 2.

This is what I've come up with:

- The subnet mask is 255.255.255.128
- The network address is 192.168.14.128

There are a total of 128 available addresses (including the network address and broadcast address)

To divide the network we create two subnets:

- 192.168.14.128/26
- 192.168.14.192/26

This will have a subnet mask of 255.255.255.192

Am I missing anything, or is this correct?

Comment: Please see the [FAQ](http://serverfault.com/faq); this is a site for professional sysadmins and this looks like a homework question. That said, I'm assuming it's a typo, but you've dropped to 68 instead of 168. Otherwise, it's all fine.

Comment: Fair enough, thank you. (It is a hw question, but I couldn't tag it as hw, now i know why.)

Comment: you have seen this question?  http://serverfault.com/questions/49765/how-does-ipv4-subnetting-work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, everything is correct in your calculations.